# Can't retrieve data from WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to retrieve the posts by using an array of ID. I have this array

```
Array ( [0] => 40 [1] => 25 )
```

And this is my code:

```
$query = WP_Query(array("p" => myCourseId()));
```

but it doesn't work. What's the error?

**New Code**

```
$ids = myCourseId();

// The Loop

$query = WP_Query(array("post__in" => $ids));
```

myCoureID() return an arry like the first i wrote

Comment: What's in `myCourseId()`?

Comment: sorry, myCourseId return the first array i wrote

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters - you want `post__in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do the same thing with get_posts instead, like this:

```
$ids = array(40,25);
$args = array(                        
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,    
    'orderby'=>'post__in',                        
    'post__in'=>$ids
 ); 
$query = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: it doesnt work! I can't understand why :(

Here is my code 

`$ids = myCourseId();
    
    $args = array(                        
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,    
        'orderby'=>'post__in',                        
        'post__in'=>$ids
     ); 

    $query = get_posts($args);`

Comment: Have you tried a print_r($query)? Is it really empty? Try to add a 'post_type' arg, like this: 

$args = array(                        
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,    
 'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby'=>'post__in',                        
    'post__in'=>$ids
 );

And your function myCourseId() have to return an array like this array(40, 25) and not like this ( [0] => 40 [1] => 25 )

Comment: ah ok, the problem is the array. thanks very much! Last question, how i convert an array like this ( [0] => 40 [1] => 25 ) in one that is compatible?

Comment: $yourArray = array(40,25);

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$myArrayOfIds = array(40, 25);
$query = WP_Query(array("post__in" => myArrayOfIds));
```

Comment: doesn't work

$ids = myCourseId();

    // The Loop

    $query = WP_Query(array("post__in" => $ids));

Comment: Please be more descriptive - we're trying to help here. What doesn't work? What is the error? You should try doing it without your additional `myCourseId()` function first to simplify the problem. If your `WP_Query(array("post__in" => $ids));` line doesn't work, then I bet your `$ids` variable is not an array, or is an associative array.

Comment: it doesn't work also without myCourseId().If i write     $query = new WP_Query( array('post__in' => array(40));
it doesn't disply anything